# Is the term "heat transfer" correct?

Tags: thermodynamics, terminology

"Heat" can be defined as:
"energy in transfer to or from a thermodynamic system" (From Wikipedia).
I have seen other definitions, but they all include the term "transfer".

A search in google scholar for "heat transfer" yields almost two million results.

But if "transfer" is already in the definition of "heat", then it would follow logically that "heat transfer" is redundant.

For example, from the same article in Wikipedia:

"Like thermodynamic work, heat transfer is a process involving more than one system, not a property of any one system."

Substituting with the definition, we get:
"Like thermodynamic work, energy in trasnfer to or from a thermodynamic system transfer is a process involving more than one system, not a property of any one system." This of course does not make sense, unless they are referring to some sort of second order transfer of transfer, which I suspect they are not.

It would make much more sense (to me at least) to simply write:
"Like thermodynamic work, heat is a process involving more than one system, not a property of any one system."

So, 2 million physics texts seem to be wrong, many in their titles, many being lengthy specialized books. This it is hard to believe. I guess I am missing something.

The question is: Is the term "heat transfer" correct, or is it redundant?

Comment: Heat is the amount of energy transferred.  Heat transfer is how the energy gets there.  Why are you wasting your valuable time pondering something like this, when you could use it profitably by solving practice problems.

Comment: I just realized that I falsely assumed that all google scholar results to the search "heat transfer" are physics texts. Many are, but many might not be. I apologize for that.

Comment: Eneas, you seem to be caught up in un-important details. What Chet Miller says is correct, and you shouldn't take the word "heat transfer" too literally.

Comment: Chet, it is about rigor. When a definition is not consistent with its use, the definition should be amended, or used properly. Sorry if I wasted your time. To me, it is interesting as it was confusing while reading about themodynamics.

Comment: Felis and Chet. Thank you for your comments. I agree that it is not too important once you grasp it, but as a layperson, it helps to read definitions which are consistent with their use. And I did spend several hours trying to understand an introductory thermodynamics text because of the inconsistency. Again, sorry if someone feels I am wasting their time with my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heat is the energy *that is* (as in specifying the very definition of heat) in transfer to or from a thermodynamic system.
Heat is talked about only during the transfer of energy. That's why *heat* and *transfer* go along. A body is not said to be retaining heat but is said to be retaining *internal energy*. But when this energy transfers from a thermodynamic system to another, it is by either heat transfer or work done as the first law of thermodynamics says.